# MySQL seems to change utf-8 encodings from '\xce\x94' to '\\xce\\x94'. How can I avoid this?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am currently working on writing csv-tables into a sql database using python3 and MySQLdb.

This is part of the code I use:

```
import MySQLdb as mbd
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import os

#establish a connection to mysql
conn = mbd.connect(host='localhost',
               user = 'me',
               passwd = '****',
               use_unicode=True, 
               charset="utf8")

file_ = "./stackoverflow_example.tsv"

df = pd.read_csv(file_, sep = '\t', engine='python', 
             quotechar='"', decimal='.', encoding='utf-8')

df_name = os.path.basename(file_)[:-4] 

df.name = df_name

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://me:****@localhost/me?charset=utf8')

df.to_sql(con = engine, name = df.name, if_exists = 'replace', 
         index = False)
```

A stated in the titel, the symbol "Δ" can be read by pandas and gets displayed as b'\xce\x94' (encoded).
When I run the code above I get an error message stating that "\xce\x94" is an invalid symbol.
OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xCE\\x9463'

How can I avoid that the extra '\' get added while writing the table in the database?

I tested it with the following content for the tsv file:
(Sorry, I dont know how to display tsv content better)

Source_[First_Author] Year  Mutations   Mutations

Raamsdonk   2000    trp-1-Δ63   leu2-Δ1

---

MySQL version: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your posted code is minimal, but not complete or verifiable. Include a sample of the CSV file that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I executed the code above (with correct database names and pwassword) and managed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: No, i did not get any errors with your code my df is `pd.DataFrame(data={"msg":["Δ"]})`. Maybe the reason associates with your `df` encoding.